# What is the best way(lambda, extension or Regular expression) of removing the white space

Tags: c#

At present I am using the below

```
private static string RemoveWhiteSpace(string text)
        {
            string trim = text.Replace(" ", "");
            trim = trim.Replace("\r", "");
            trim = trim.Replace("\n", "");
            trim = trim.Replace("\t", "");
            return trim;
        }
```

Looking for a better way
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? More performant? More readable? You can iterate over each char of the string, and add the non blank ones to a StringBuilder.

Comment: I would recommend against using the name `trim` for this string.  I find the name a bit counterintuitive since you are performing replacement rather than trimming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");

s = r.Replace(s,string.Empty);
```

that is shorter and probably still readable.

Comment: @Tengiz, the user intent was clear because replace works even into the string.

Comment: `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+");` is shorter.  Not sure if the + makes things more or less efficient.  If its a function that will be called a lot, making a static compiled instance of the Regex might make things faster.

Comment: @Brian yes, true, useful addition.

Answer (score 4):

What sort of "better" are you looking for? You certainly *could* use a regular expression, either to replace your existing behaviour or to make it match more whitespace, but you need to be clear about what the objective is.

It's *possible* that a change will improve performance - but you'd have to measure it to be sure. Is this currently a performance bottleneck?

What I like about the current method is that it's incredibly obvious what's going on. If you're going to lose that simplicity, you'd better be sure that the benefit is worth it. In particular, if you use a regular expression whitespace matcher, you need to be sure that you really *do* want all the various kinds of whitespace removed - it won't be doing exactly the same job as your current code. Work out what you want the behaviour to be, and then find the simplest way of implementing that exact behaviour.

One slight simplificiation is to use method chaining:

```
private static string RemoveWhiteSpace(string text)
{
    return text.Replace(" ", "")
               .Replace("\r", "")
               .Replace("\n", "")
               .Replace("\t", "");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be StringBuilder better than 4 strings?

Comment: @TcKs: Possibly. It would probably depend on the size of the strings being trimmed etc. But we don't even know whether performance is what the OP is concerned about - that should be the first thing to find out: what the OP is trying to improve.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static string RemoveWhiteSpace(string text) {
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
    foreach(char c in text) {
        if ( false == char.IsWhiteSpace(c) ) { ret.Append(c); }
    }

    return ret.ToString();
}
```

You can try use for loop instead of foreach. Maybe it will be faster.

Comment: I prefer this method as it only iterates the string once, only generates one new string object, and I'm not crazy about RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the regex approach personally if you are sure you want to eliminate all white space.

```
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", "");
```

Comment: Why use so complex way for easy task?

Comment: @TcKs  I am assuming you responded before I adjusted my code to match the original question.  But either way, what is complex about it?

Comment: The complex is "body" of Regex class. The regex is great tool for complex string manipulations. But if you want remove whitespaces, there are better ways which does not consume too much CPU and RAM.

Answer (score -1):

This is better:

```
return trim.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n', '\t')
```

but it will not replace from inside the string... I am not sure if it's what you need though.

Comment: You still need text.Replace(" ", ""); to remove white spaces between the words.

Comment: @David Martinez text.Replace(" ", "") does not works on tab in the middle

Comment: furthermore, Trim *already* trims "\t\r\n"+blank, so non need to explicit pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score -3):

You could change the last 3 lines with Trim function from string class

```
trim.Trim();
```

Comment: No, `Trim` removes only leading and trailing characters, not characters in the middle.